# output pictures to selected directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using Real-ESRGAN to upscale images
https://github.com/xinntao/Real-ESRGAN

It works by drag&dropping images to Real-ESRGAN file however if i drag multiple photos it is upscalling only one photo multiple times and second thing is it possible to upload upscalled images to certain directory

I am not a programmer, can somebody help me modify this short script? Thanks in advance.

code from Real-ESRGAN file

```bash
@echo off
for %%a in (%*) do ("%~dp0"\realesrgan-ncnn-vulkan.exe -i "%~1" -o "%~dp1\%~n1"_4x.png -n realesrgan-x4plus-anime
"%~dp1\%~n1_4x.png"
)
exit
```

Comment: FYI, please doublequote paths correctly; change `"%~dp0"\realesrgan-ncnn-vulkan.exe` to `"%~dp0realesrgan-ncnn-vulkan.exe"`, and `"%~dp1\%~n1"_4x.png` to `"%~dpn1_4x.png"`.